# How can I create a new database using Entity Framework Code First programmatically?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an MVC application that companies can be sign up and have some datas. When a company signed up, I want to create a database for company signed up, but I want to use entity framework with MySQL. How can I do this?

**This is my DbContext;**

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class CompanyModel : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<siteler> siteler { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<kazanlar> kazanlar { get; set; }

    public CompanyModel() : base()
    {

    }
}

public class siteler
{
    [Key]
    public int site_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(45)]
    public string site_adi { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int il_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ilce_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(140)]
    public string adres { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime olusturma_tarihi { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool aktif { get; set; }
}

public class kazanlar
{
    [Key]
    public int kazan_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(12)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string kazan_no { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int site_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal okuma_ucreti { get; set; }
}
```

**This is my MySQL Connection String**

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="mysqlroot" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Uid=root;Pwd=xxxx;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Dont create a database, just add information to a table in one database identifying the new signup

Comment: There is another database I already have for this.

Comment: Companies which is going to sign up have different data types and much data. So I want to separate their databases to gain performance and avoid from complication. In my scenario, each company will connect to their own database and perform their transactions and queries on their own database.